# Laravel Unit Test with Session Facade fails on HHVM

Tags: php, unit-testing, session, hhvm

When I use the Session facade within a Laravel Test, I get failures within HHVM systems. I'm using Travis.CI to test a range of systems from PHP 5.4 right up to PHP 7, including HHVM. Throughout my range of tests, wherever Sessions are used, the tests fail, but only on HHVM systems; all others pass.

Here's an example test:

```
/**
 * Tests that, provided all the data lines up, we can add points to a child
 */
public function testPointAdditionWithCorrectChild()
{
    Session::start();
    // Set up User
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();
    $this->be($user);
    // Create Child
    $child = factory(Child::class)->create([
        'user_id' => $user->id
    ]);
    // Set up Request
    $pointData = [
        '_token' => csrf_token(),
        'child' => $child->id,
        'points' => mt_rand(1, 10)
    ];
    $this->post('/point/increment', $pointData);
    // Assertion
    $this->seeInDatabase('points', [
        'child_id' => $pointData['child'],
        'point_difference' => $pointData['points']
    ]);
}
```

The purpose of the above test is to ensure that my middleware functions when authenticating a child against a user with the correct credentials - restricting the ability to add/remove points so that only the user who created the child is allowed to do this.

Laravel comes with a `$this->withoutMiddleware();` flag which allows me to turn off middleware for a particular test. However, as I'm testing my middleware in this instane, I cannot use it, meaning I also have to satisfy the all the other middlewares assigned to the controller as well, such as the VerifyCsrfToken middleware. To do this, I have to run `Session::start()` otherwise I cannot take advantage of the `csrf_token()` function. Therein lies my problem. I suppose it's an integration test, more than a unit test.

Is there something specific about the way that HHVM deals with sessions that is causing these tests to fail?

Comment: What happens when you run this test? What exactly doesn't work? What output gets produced? What of that output is unusual?

Comment: @JoshWatzman The `seeInDatabase` function asserts that the item exists in the specified table. With HHVM, this returns false, on all others it returns true. I've traced the issue and it's that I'm being given an `Invalid CSRF token` error on the `points/increment` endpoint. `csrf_token()` depends on an active session. This only happens on HHVM, and not on any other system, I test with.